How to Localize Button Labels in discord.py Based on User Locale or Guild Settings?
I am using discord.py to build a Discord bot that includes interactive views with buttons. Each button performs specific actions related to message embed manipulation. I want to localize the button labels so they are displayed in the user's locale or default to the guild's locale. Below is a simplified version of my setup:
class EmbedCreatorView(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="commands.admin.embed.buttons.setTitle", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def set_title(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        ...
        # Modal interaction here

    # More buttons with similar structure...

The button labels are initialized with keys for localization. Here's how I localize strings within interaction responses:
await interaction.response.send_message(tanjunLocalizer.localize(
    self.commandInfo.locale, "commands.admin.embed.previewSent"
), ephemeral=True)

tanjunLocalizer is just my implementation of a localzer
So my questions are:

How can I dynamically set the button labels based on each user's locale at the time of interaction?
If individual user localization isn't feasible, how can I set the labels based on the guild's default locale?


Quite simply, you can dynamically add buttons with View.add_item.
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_button()

    def add_button(self):
        button_1 = discord.ui.Button(label="1")
        button_1.callback = ...
        self.add_item(button_1)

Now, you can parse an argument to __init__, whether it be the button label or the guild for processing in add_button.
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, button_label):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_buttons(button_label) #  Or store in self
    ...

@command()
async def command(...):
    label = #  get locale
    await send(view=MyView(label))


So there are no Dynamic localized button labels like with e.g. slash commands?

Locale in Discord.py usually refers to text being translated to different languages. In your question, it seems like you asked about the button labels changing based on who was running the command or the guild is was ran in. If you're talking about button labels that looks different for everyone, then that's not possible.
